# Unable to execute Liquibase update commands via Docker run

Tags: postgresql, liquibase, bamboo

I am using docker here to build Liquibase and trying to execute Liquibase commands on fly.

Here is the Dockerfile:-

```
FROM liquibase/liquibase
RUN lpm add mysql --global
```

I am using below command on fly

```
docker run --rm -v ${bamboo.build.working.directory}/:/liquibase/changelog liquibase/liquibase --url="jdbc:postgresql://app-liquibase-test.us-region.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/database?currentSchema=schema" --changeLogFile=sql/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml --username=username --password=password update
```

I am getting below error:-

```
error   04-May-2022 22:08:38    Starting Liquibase at 05:08:38 (version 4.9.1 #1978 built at 2022-03-28 19:39+0000)
error   04-May-2022 22:08:38    Liquibase Version: 4.9.1
error   04-May-2022 22:08:38    Liquibase Community 4.9.1 by Liquibase
error   04-May-2022 22:08:48    
error   04-May-2022 22:08:48     Unexpected error running Liquibase: Connection could not be created to jdbc:postgresql://app-liquibase-test.us-region.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/database?currentSchema=schema with driver org.postgresql.Driver. The connection attempt failed.
```

Please suggest

Comment: in the Docker run command, is "databse" intended or a typo there?

Comment: @EduardUta It is intended. Let me edit it to correct name

Answer (score 0):

From [this October 2021 GitHub issue](https://github.com/liquibase/docker/issues/129), you need to use single quotes around your JDBC driver URL instead of double-quotes. Try entering it as edited below.

```
docker run --rm -v ${bamboo.build.working.directory}/:/liquibase/changelog liquibase/liquibase --url='jdbc:postgresql://app-liquibase-test.us-region.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/database?currentSchema=schema' --changeLogFile=sql/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml --username=username --password=password update
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @tabbyfoo . I have used single quote as suggest by you and still I see same error. I have updated the error message accordingly.

Comment: On your post on the Liquibase Forum, MikeOlivas replied with the information below. I can follow up with him for you if you can answer this question: Does the system that is running docker have access (in the security group) to connect to
app-liquibase-test.us-region.rds.amazonaws.com:5432. on port 5432.